# Find the variance of $X$ given joint pf

Tags: probability, statistics

$$
\begin{array}{l}
f(x,y) \\[4pt]
\begin{array}{|c|cc|}
\hline
{\Large _y \backslash^x} &  0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0.1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 14 \\
2 & 0.02 & 21 \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

> Find the variance of $x$ ,  ($\text{Var} (X))$

I calculated that

$$\text{Var } (X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$$ correct?

Comment: How do you calculate expectations? $E[X^2]\ne f(1,1)+f(1,0)$ and $E[X]\ne f(1,1)+f(1,0)$ too. Check definition of expected value of discrete distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You need $f(1,0) + f(1,1) + f(1,2) = 0.21 + 0.4 + 0.09 = 0.7$ where you have $f(1,1) + f(1,0).$

Answer (score 0):

Note: $$P_X(X=x)=\displaystyle{\sum_{all\,y}}P_{XY}(x,y)$$

Hence:
$$\begin{align}Var(X)&=E\left[X^2\right]-\left(E\left[X\right]\right)^2\\
                     &=\displaystyle{\sum_{all\,x}x^2P_X(x)}-\left(\sum_{all\,x}xP_X(x)\right)^2\\
                     &=0.7-0.49\\
                     &=0.21
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{|c|cc|c|}
\hline
\Large _y \backslash^x  & 0 & 1&f(y)\\
\hline
  0 & 0.09 & 0.21&0.30\\
 1 & 0.20 & 0.40&0.60\\
  2 & 0.01 & 0.09&0.10\\
 \hline
f(x)& 0.30 & 0.70&1.00\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$$E(X)= (0\times 0.30) + (1\times 0.70) = 0.70$$
$$E(X^{2})=(0^2\times 0.30) + (1^2\times 0.70) = 0.70$$
$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=0.70 - (0.70)^2 = 0.21$$